# How to create a private custom event or how to handle/apply event-dispatching in the most protected way possible?

Tags: javascript, dom, events, protected, custom-events

I would like to create a private custom event, an event nobody else can dispatch or listen. I tried this, but it does not work:

```js
new CustomEvent(Symbol("validate"));
```

Is it possible?

I know I can use a random string for the name of an event.

Comment: `nobody else can dispatch or listen` then who can `dispatch` or `listen`? Clearly explain what you are trying to achive?

Comment: The CustomEvent has to have a 'string' type, and that means in principle anybody who knows the string can listen - is that a problem for you? Even if your string is randomized and unpredictable? If that's still a problem for you, consider encrypting the details you pass in the event.

Comment: For further obfuscation: Write your own event dispatcher/handler

Comment: `new CustomEvent(crypto.randomUUID());` then how will *your code* listen for it?  Sounds like you don't want an `event` at all.  Provide a point in the "listener" for the "dispatcher" to call directly.   Though it's hard to determine what you mean by "nobody else".

Comment: @BadPiggie If you kill everybody else, who is still alive?

Comment: @TKoL You mean even if it would be possible to use a private symbol, everybody would be able to sniff it, because every event bubbles around?

Comment: @ceving ... 1/2 ... Does the question exclusively target `CustomEvent`s dispatched by DOM nodes? In that case ... a) if just your code implements the dispatching logic and the consumers of the dispatched custom events, no-one else can listen to or intercept such events as long as the event-type can not be easily / accidentally guessed. (One could e.g. utilize an uuid shared amongst your code in that case) ...

Comment: @ceving ... 2/2 ... b) if your code implements the dispatching logic, the consumers of the dispatched custom events are trusted and no-one else than such consumers and third party dom/event libraries is involved, you are responsible for choosing a non colliding name for the custom event-type. And this is already safe enough for code, loosely coupled by events.

Comment: @ceving ... Regarding all the comments, explanations, code examples, are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0):

From some of the OP's and my comments ...

> Of cause one could build a system which encloses/encapsulates everything except for e.g. an instance's ***de/register*** / ***un/subscribe*** methods where one could add/remove objects which each feature an own (event/topic/subject/channel specific) handler function. The dispatching instance does not have a public `dispatchEvent` method but would invoke each registered/subscribed object's specific handler function. [Something similar to this ...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77747421/2627243) – Peter Seliger

> > @PeterSeliger The problem with the event-strings is: they share one global name-space. Nothing prevents collisions. – ceving

> > > Nope ... if one [privately] ties an own `EventTarget` instance to every instance of a type which is capable of dispatching events to selected (validated and registered) objects, no one except the secretly/privately dispatching instance itself is capable of accessing such dispatched events and its related data. This is due to just the dispatching instance itself can access the dispatching object. The instance itself controls the de/registering of objects which each have to be capable of handling such controlled dispatched (and otherwise not accessible) event-types. – Peter Seliger

And regarding especially ...

> *"The problem with the event-strings is: they share one global name-space. Nothing prevents collisions."* – ceving

... the event-dispatching of [`EventTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) implements a type-safe [***Signals and Slot***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signals_and_slots) approach. Nobody can fake / intercept / spoof the [event-object](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-event) which gets created at the [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)'s  invocation time. In addition, at an event-target's [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) time only the event-type specific handler-functions (each assigned as an created event-listener's [`handleEvent`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-eventtarget) method) which have been registered at this very event-target are going to be invoked.

Combining, like suggested (and later demonstrated), a pub-sub implementation via `addSubscriber/s` / `removeSubscriber/s` with the enclosed (privately held)  functionality of an event-target, enables both, the privacy and the type-safety of event-dispatching.

```js
const subscriber_1 = {
  uuid: crypto.randomUUID(),
  handleTypeA(evt) {
    console.log({
      eventType: evt.type,
      currentTarget: evt.currentTarget,
      targetConstructorName: evt.detail.target.constructor.name,
      subscriber: subscriber_1,
      payload: evt.detail.payload,
    });
  }
};
const subscriber_2 = {
  uuid: crypto.randomUUID(),
  handleTypeB(evt) {
    console.log({
      eventType: evt.type,
      currentTarget: evt.currentTarget,
      targetConstructorName: evt.detail.target.constructor.name,
      subscriber: subscriber_2,
      payload: evt.detail.payload,
    });
  }
};
const subscriber_3 = {
  uuid: crypto.randomUUID(),
  handleTypeB(evt) {
    console.log({
      eventType: evt.type,
      currentTarget: evt.currentTarget,
      targetConstructorName: evt.detail.target.constructor.name,
      subscriber: subscriber_3,
      payload: evt.detail.payload,
    });
  },
  handleTypeZ(evt) {
    console.log({
      eventType: evt.type,
      currentTarget: evt.currentTarget,
      targetConstructorName: evt.detail.target.constructor.name,
      subscriber: subscriber_3,
      payload: evt.detail.payload,
    });
  }
};
const sampleInstance = new PrivatlyDispatchingType;

console.log(
  'sampleInstance.addSubscribers(subscriber_1, subscriber_2, subscriber_3) ...\n',
  '... sampleInstance.aggregatesAndDispatchesSampleData() ...',
);
sampleInstance.addSubscribers(subscriber_1, subscriber_2, subscriber_3);
sampleInstance.aggregatesAndDispatchesSampleData();

console.log(
  'sampleInstance.removeSubscribers([subscriber_1, subscriber_3]) ...\n',
  '... sampleInstance.aggregatesAndDispatchesSampleData() ...',
);
sampleInstance.removeSubscribers([subscriber_1, subscriber_3]);
sampleInstance.aggregatesAndDispatchesSampleData();;

console.log(
  'sampleInstance.removeSubscribers(subscriber_2) ...\n',
  '... sampleInstance.aggregatesAndDispatchesSampleData() ...',
);
sampleInstance.removeSubscribers(subscriber_2);
sampleInstance.aggregatesAndDispatchesSampleData();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
// scope of module ... `PrivatlyDispatchingType`

function isValidSubscriber(value) {
  // e.g. implement other custom type check functionality.
  return (
    (typeof value?.uuid === 'string') &&
    (Object
      .entries(value)
      .filter(([key, value]) =>
        key.startsWith('handle') && (typeof value === 'function')
      )
      .length >= 1)      
  );
}

function getValidSubscribers(...subscribers) {
  return subscribers.flat().filter(isValidSubscriber);
}

// a contract like lookup.
//
// - A subscriber has to feature an especially named method
//   (here the lookup-table's key) in order to get notified.
// - Thus, the type/name of any of the later from exclusively
//   intern/protected dispatched events does not even matter.
//
const eventTypeLookup = {
  handleTypeA: 'private-event-type-A',
  handleTypeB: 'private-event-type-B',
  handleTypeZ: 'private-event-type-Z',
}

class PrivatlyDispatchingType {
  #dispatcher = new EventTarget;
  #subscribers = new Map;

  /**
   *  type specific implementation
   */

  //  ----- ----- ----- ----- -----

  addSubscribers(...args) {
    getValidSubscribers(...args)

      .forEach(subscriber => {
        const { uuid } = subscriber;

        if (!this.#subscribers.has(uuid)) {
          this.#subscribers.set(uuid, subscriber);

          Object
            .entries(subscriber)
            .filter(([key, value]) =>
              key.startsWith('handle') && (typeof value === 'function')
            )
            .forEach(([handlerName, handlerFunction]) =>

              this.#dispatcher.addEventListener(
                eventTypeLookup[handlerName], handlerFunction
              )
            );
        }
      });
  }
  removeSubscribers(...args) {
    getValidSubscribers(...args)

      .forEach(subscriber => {
        const { uuid } = subscriber;

        if (this.#subscribers.has(uuid)) {
          this.#subscribers.delete(uuid);

          Object
            .entries(subscriber)
            .filter(([key, value]) =>
              key.startsWith('handle') && (typeof value === 'function')
            )
            .forEach(([handlerName, handlerFunction]) =>

              this.#dispatcher.removeEventListener(
                eventTypeLookup[handlerName], handlerFunction
              )
            );
        }
      });
  }

  aggregatesAndDispatchesSampleData() {
    this.#dispatcher.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(
      'private-event-type-A', {
        detail: {
          target: this,
          payload: {
            foo: 'Foo',
            bar: 'Bar',
          }
        }
      })
    );
    this.#dispatcher.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(
      'private-event-type-B', {
        detail: {
          target: this,
          payload: {
            baz: 'Baz',
            biz: 'Biz',
          }
        }
      })
    );
    this.#dispatcher.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(
      'private-event-type-Z', {
        detail: {
          target: this,
          payload: {
            quick: 'quick',
            brown: 'brown',
            fox: 'fox',
          }
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
</script>
```

**Code re-use of *"Exclusive Publishing Behavior"***

The next provided example code demonstrates a possible way of **code re-use, which still enables the *exclusive publishing***.

The implementation does achieve such behavior by utilizing a single `WeakMap` instance for covering the privacy part of the re-usable implemented `ExclusivePublisher` code. The latter class nevertheless can not be allowed to be directly instantiated by third party code that wants to acquire exclusive publishing behavior. Instead the `"exclusive-publishing"` module exposes a single `useExclusivePublishing` method which grands access to an `ExclusivePublisher` instance's ***publisher*** and ***dispatcher*** functionality.

Thus, any third party code which consumes the `publisher` and `dispatcher` return values of `useExclusivePublishing` **first** has to keep both references private and **second** needs to implement forwarding code for `addSubscribers` and `removeSubscribers` and in addition needs to implement its own publishing code built around the `dispatcher`'s `dispatchEvent` method.

```js
// import { useExclusivePublishing } from 'exclusive-publishing.js'

class MyExclusivePublishingType {
  #publisher;
  #dispatcher;

  constructor(eventTypes, isSubscriber) {

    const { publisher, dispatcher } =
      useExclusivePublishing(eventTypes, isSubscriber);

    // private property based aggregation.
    this.#publisher = publisher;
    this.#dispatcher = dispatcher;    
  }

  // forwarding via aggregated private properties.

  addSubscribers(...args) {
    return this.#publisher.addSubscribers(...args);
  }
  removeSubscribers(...args) {
    return this.#publisher.removeSubscribers(...args);
  }

  // type-specific prototypal implementation/s.

  publishSampleData() {
    this.#dispatcher.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(
      'private-event-type-A', {
        detail: {
          target: this,
          payload: {
            foo: 'Foo',
            bar: 'Bar',
          }
        }
      })
    );
    this.#dispatcher.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(
      'private-event-type-B', {
        detail: {
          target: this,
          payload: {
            baz: 'Baz',
            biz: 'Biz',
          }
        }
      })
    );
    this.#dispatcher.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(
      'private-event-type-Z', {
        detail: {
          target: this,
          payload: {
            quick: 'quick',
            brown: 'brown',
            fox: 'fox',
          }
        }
      })
    );
  }
}

const publishingType = new MyExclusivePublishingType({
  handleTypeA: 'private-event-type-A',
  handleTypeB: 'private-event-type-B',
  handleTypeZ: 'private-event-type-Z',
});

const subscriber_1 = {
  uuid: crypto.randomUUID(),
  handleTypeA(evt) {
    console.log({
      eventType: evt.type,
      currentTarget: evt.currentTarget,
      targetConstructorName: evt.detail.target.constructor.name,
      subscriber: subscriber_1,
      payload: evt.detail.payload,
    });
  }
};
const subscriber_2 = {
  uuid: crypto.randomUUID(),
  handleTypeB(evt) {
    console.log({
      eventType: evt.type,
      currentTarget: evt.currentTarget,
      targetConstructorName: evt.detail.target.constructor.name,
      subscriber: subscriber_2,
      payload: evt.detail.payload,
    });
  }
};
const subscriber_3 = {
  uuid: crypto.randomUUID(),
  handleTypeB(evt) {
    console.log({
      eventType: evt.type,
      currentTarget: evt.currentTarget,
      targetConstructorName: evt.detail.target.constructor.name,
      subscriber: subscriber_3,
      payload: evt.detail.payload,
    });
  },
  handleTypeZ(evt) {
    console.log({
      eventType: evt.type,
      currentTarget: evt.currentTarget,
      targetConstructorName: evt.detail.target.constructor.name,
      subscriber: subscriber_3,
      payload: evt.detail.payload,
    });
  }
};

console.log(
  'publishingType.addSubscribers(subscriber_1, subscriber_2, subscriber_3) ...\n',
  '... publishingType.publishSampleData() ...',
);
publishingType.addSubscribers(subscriber_1, subscriber_2, subscriber_3);
publishingType.publishSampleData();

console.log(
  'publishingType.removeSubscribers([subscriber_1, subscriber_3]) ...\n',
  '... publishingType.publishSampleData() ...',
);
publishingType.removeSubscribers([subscriber_1, subscriber_3]);
publishingType.publishSampleData();;

console.log(
  'publishingType.removeSubscribers(subscriber_2) ...\n',
  '... publishingType.publishSampleData() ...',
);
publishingType.removeSubscribers(subscriber_2);
publishingType.publishSampleData();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
// scope of module ... "exclusive-publishing.js"

const publisherRegistry = new WeakMap;

function isFunction(value) {
  return (
    (typeof value === 'function') &&
    (typeof value.call === 'function') &&
    (typeof value.apply === 'function')
  );
}

function isMinimumSubscriber(value) {
  return (
    (typeof value?.uuid === 'string') &&
    (Object
      .entries(value)
      .filter(([key, value]) =>
        key.startsWith('handle') && isFunction(value)
      )
      .length >= 1)      
  );
}

function getSubscribers(isSubscriber, ...subscribers) {
  return subscribers.flat().filter(isSubscriber);
}
function getHandlerEntries(subscriber) {
  return Object
    .entries(subscriber)
    .filter(([key, value]) =>
      key.startsWith('handle') && isFunction(value)
    );
}

function addSubscribers(publisher, ...args) {
  const {
    eventTypes, dispatcher, subscribers: subscriberRegistry, isSubscriber,
  } =
    publisherRegistry.get(publisher);

  getSubscribers(isSubscriber, ...args)
    .forEach(subscriber => {
      const { uuid } = subscriber;

      if (!subscriberRegistry.has(uuid)) {
        subscriberRegistry.set(uuid, subscriber);

        getHandlerEntries(subscriber)
          .forEach(([handlerName, handlerFunction]) =>

            dispatcher.addEventListener(
              eventTypes[handlerName], handlerFunction
            )
          );
      }
    });
}
function removeSubscribers(publisher, ...args) {
  const {
    eventTypes, dispatcher, subscribers: subscriberRegistry, isSubscriber,
  } =
    publisherRegistry.get(publisher);

  getSubscribers(isSubscriber, ...args)
    .forEach(subscriber => {
      const { uuid } = subscriber;

      if (subscriberRegistry.has(uuid)) {
        subscriberRegistry.delete(uuid);

        getHandlerEntries(subscriber)
          .forEach(([handlerName, handlerFunction]) =>

            dispatcher.removeEventListener(
              eventTypes[handlerName], handlerFunction
            )
          );
      }
    });
}

class ExclusivePublisher {
  constructor(eventTypes = {}, isSubscriber) {

    publisherRegistry
      .set(this, {
        eventTypes,
        dispatcher: new EventTarget,
        subscribers: new Map,
        isSubscriber: isFunction(isSubscriber)
          && (value => isMinimumSubscriber(value) && isSubscriber(value))
          || isMinimumSubscriber,
      });
  }

  // - minimum prototypal implementation/footprint because of fowarding
  //   which is possible due to the `WeakMap`-based privacy-approach.

  addSubscribers(...args) {
    return addSubscribers(this, ...args);
  }
  removeSubscribers(...args) {
    return removeSubscribers(this, ...args);
  }
}

/*export */function useExclusivePublishing(eventTypes, isSubscriber) {

  const publisher = new ExclusivePublisher(eventTypes, isSubscriber);
  const { dispatcher } =  publisherRegistry.get(publisher);

  return {
    publisher, dispatcher,
  };
}
</script>
```

The practicability, re-usability and the advantages of the *"Exclusive Publishing Behavior"* are going to be demonstrated once again by rewriting the example-code of one of my recently provided answers ... [*"With Node EventEmitter, how would one remove an object from a service's list while also un-subscribing from the service's event-dispatching?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77747421/2627243).

Regarding the last example code of the just referred answer ... instead of the `Bakery` class letting extend `EventTarget` which allows everyone with access to a bakery-instance to invoke all of its 3 inherited methods (`add/removeEventListener` / `dispatchEvent`), one would implement a `Bakery` class with the help of `useExclusivePublishing` of the further above introduced `'exclusive-publishing'` module.

```js
// import { Bakery } from './bakery.js';
// import { Customer } from './customer.js';

const klugesherz =
  new Bakery({ name: 'Pâtisserie Klugesherz', breadPrice: 1.5 });
const hanss =
  new Bakery({ name: 'Boulangerie Patisserie Hanss', breadPrice: 2.7 });

const johnRich = new Customer({
  name: 'John Rich',
  maxPrice: 5,
  moneyTotal: 20,
  handlePurchaseBread: function ({ detail: { bakery } }) {
    this.buyBread(bakery, 3);
  },
});
const martinPoor = new Customer({
  name: 'Martin Poor',
  maxPrice: 3,
  moneyTotal: 10,
  handlePurchaseBread: function ({ detail: { bakery } }) {
    const quantity = (
      ((bakery.name === 'Boulangerie Patisserie Hanss') && 1) ||
      ((bakery.name === 'Pâtisserie Klugesherz') && 2) || 0
    );
    this.buyBread(bakery, quantity);
  },
});

klugesherz.addCustomers(johnRich, martinPoor);
hanss.addCustomers(johnRich, martinPoor);

console.log({
  bakeries: {
    klugesherz: klugesherz.valueOf(),
    hanss: hanss.valueOf(),
  },
  customers: {
    johnRich: johnRich.valueOf(),
    martinPoor: martinPoor.valueOf(),
  },
});

console.log('\n+++ klugesherz.bakeBread(4) +++');
klugesherz.bakeBread(4);

console.log('\n+++ hanss.bakeBread(5) +++');
hanss.bakeBread(5);

console.log('\n+++ klugesherz.bakeBread(4) +++');
klugesherz.bakeBread(4);

console.log('\n+++ hanss.bakeBread(5) +++');
hanss.bakeBread(5);

console.log('\n... remove John Rich from the customer list of Patisserie Hanss.\n\n');
hanss.removeCustomers(johnRich);

console.log('\n+++ klugesherz.bakeBread(4) +++');
klugesherz.bakeBread(4);

console.log('\n+++ hanss.bakeBread(5) +++');
hanss.bakeBread(5);

console.log('\n... remove Martin Poor from the customer list of Patisserie Hanss.');
hanss.removeCustomers(martinPoor);

console.log('... remove John Rich and Martin Poor from the customer list of Pâtisserie Klugesherz.\n\n');
klugesherz.removeCustomers(johnRich, martinPoor);

console.log('+++ klugesherz.bakeBread(4) +++');
klugesherz.bakeBread(4);

console.log('+++ hanss.bakeBread(5) +++');
hanss.bakeBread(5);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
// scope of module ... "exclusive-publishing.js"

const publisherRegistry = new WeakMap;

function isFunction(value) {
  return (
    (typeof value === 'function') &&
    (typeof value.call === 'function') &&
    (typeof value.apply === 'function')
  );
}

function isMinimumSubscriber(subscriber) {
  return (
    (typeof subscriber?.uuid === 'string') &&
    (Object
      .entries(subscriber.valueOf?.() ?? subscriber)
      .filter(([key, value]) =>
        key.startsWith('handle') && isFunction(value)
      )
      .length >= 1)      
  );
}

function getSubscribers(isSubscriber, ...subscribers) {
  return subscribers.flat().filter(isSubscriber);
}
function getHandlerEntries(subscriber) {
  return Object
    .entries(subscriber.valueOf?.() ?? subscriber)
    .filter(([key, value]) =>
      key.startsWith('handle') && isFunction(value)
    );
}

function addSubscribers(publisher, ...args) {
  const {
    eventTypes, dispatcher, subscribers: subscriberRegistry, isSubscriber,
  } =
    publisherRegistry.get(publisher);

  getSubscribers(isSubscriber, ...args)
    .forEach(subscriber => {
      const { uuid } = subscriber;

      if (!subscriberRegistry.has(uuid)) {
        subscriberRegistry.set(uuid, subscriber);

        getHandlerEntries(subscriber)
          .forEach(([handlerName, handlerFunction]) =>

            dispatcher.addEventListener(
              eventTypes[handlerName], handlerFunction
            )
          );
      }
    });
}
function removeSubscribers(publisher, ...args) {
  const {
    eventTypes, dispatcher, subscribers: subscriberRegistry, isSubscriber,
  } =
    publisherRegistry.get(publisher);

  getSubscribers(isSubscriber, ...args)
    .forEach(subscriber => {
      const { uuid } = subscriber;

      if (subscriberRegistry.has(uuid)) {
        subscriberRegistry.delete(uuid);

        getHandlerEntries(subscriber)
          .forEach(([handlerName, handlerFunction]) =>

            dispatcher.removeEventListener(
              eventTypes[handlerName], handlerFunction
            )
          );
      }
    });
}

class ExclusivePublisher {
  constructor(eventTypes = {}, isSubscriber) {

    publisherRegistry
      .set(this, {
        eventTypes,
        dispatcher: new EventTarget,
        subscribers: new Map,
        isSubscriber: isFunction(isSubscriber)
          && (value => isMinimumSubscriber(value) && isSubscriber(value))
          || isMinimumSubscriber,
      });
  }

  // - minimum prototypal implementation/footprint because of fowarding
  //   which is possible due to the `WeakMap`-based privacy-approach.

  addSubscribers(...args) {
    return addSubscribers(this, ...args);
  }
  removeSubscribers(...args) {
    return removeSubscribers(this, ...args);
  }
}

/*export */function useExclusivePublishing(eventTypes, isSubscriber) {

  const publisher = new ExclusivePublisher(eventTypes, isSubscriber);
  const { dispatcher, subscribers } =  publisherRegistry.get(publisher);

  return {
    publisher, dispatcher, subscribers,
  };
}
</script>

<script>
// scope of module ... "customer.js"

/*export */class Customer {
  #uuid;
  #name;
  #maxPrice;
  #moneyTotal;
  #handlePurchaseBread;

  constructor({ name, maxPrice, moneyTotal, handlePurchaseBread }) {
    this.#uuid = crypto.randomUUID();
    this.#name = name;
    this.#maxPrice = maxPrice;
    this.#moneyTotal = moneyTotal;
    this.#handlePurchaseBread = (typeof handlePurchaseBread === 'function')
      && handlePurchaseBread.bind(this)
      || (({ currentTarget: bakery }) => { this.buyBread(bakery, 1); });
  }
  get uuid() {
    return this.#uuid;
  }
  get name() {
    return this.#name;
  }
  get maxPrice() {
    return this.#maxPrice;
  }
  get moneyTotal() {
    return this.#moneyTotal;
  }
  get handlePurchaseBread() {
    return this.#handlePurchaseBread;
  }

  buyBread(bakery, quantity = 1) {
    const { approved, reason } = bakery.sellBread(this, quantity);

    if (approved === true) {

      this.#moneyTotal = this.moneyTotal - (bakery.breadPrice * quantity);

      console.log(
        `Customer ${ this.name } bought ${ quantity } piece/s of bread for a total of ${ (bakery.breadPrice * quantity).toFixed(2) } at ${ bakery.name }.`
      );
    } else if (typeof reason === 'string') {

      console.log('Buying a bread did fail, due to ...', reason);
    }
  }

  valueOf() {
    const { uuid, name, maxPrice, moneyTotal, handlePurchaseBread } = this;
    return { uuid, name, maxPrice, moneyTotal, handlePurchaseBread };
  }
}

/*export */function isCustomer(value) {
  return ((value instanceof Customer) || (
    Object
      .keys(value.valueOf())
      .sort()
      .join('_') === 'handlePurchaseBread_maxPrice_moneyTotal_name_uuid'
  ));
}
</script>

<script>
// scope of module ... "bakery.js"

// import { useExclusivePublishing } from './exclusive-publishing.js';
// import { isCustomer } from './customer.js';

/*export */class Bakery {
  #name;

  #breadPrice;
  #breadCount;
  #moneyTotal;

  #customers;

  #publisher;
  #dispatcher;

  constructor({ name, breadPrice }) {
    this.#name = name;

    this.#breadPrice = breadPrice;
    this.#breadCount = 0;
    this.#moneyTotal = 0;

    const { publisher, dispatcher, subscribers: customers } =
      useExclusivePublishing({ handlePurchaseBread: 'bread-baked' }, isCustomer);

    this.#customers = customers;

    this.#publisher = publisher;
    this.#dispatcher = dispatcher;
  }

  get name() {
    return this.#name;
  }
  get breadPrice() {
    return this.#breadPrice;
  }
  get breadCount() {
    return this.#breadCount;
  }
  get moneyTotal() {
    return this.#moneyTotal;
  }
  get customers() {
    return [...this.#customers.values()];
  }

  addCustomers(...args) {
    return this.#publisher.addSubscribers(...args);
  }
  removeCustomers(...args) {
    return this.#publisher.removeSubscribers(...args);
  }

  bakeBread(quantity = 10) {
    this.#breadCount = this.#breadCount + quantity;

    this.#dispatcher.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent('bread-baked', { detail: { bakery: this, quantity } })
    );
  }

  sellBread(customer, quantity = 1) {
    const transaction = { approved: false };

    if (quantity >= 1) {
      if (this.breadCount >= quantity) {

        const isWithinPriceLimit = this.breadPrice <= customer.maxPrice;
        const canEffortPurchase = (this.breadPrice * quantity) <= customer.moneyTotal;

        if (isWithinPriceLimit) {
          if (canEffortPurchase) {

            this.#breadCount = this.breadCount - quantity;

            transaction.approved = true;
          } else {
            transaction.reason =
              `Customer ${ customer.name } doesn't have enough money for buying a bread at ${ this.name }.`;
          }
        } else {
          transaction.reason =
            `Customer ${ customer.name } does have a price limit which just did exceed at ${ this.name }.`;
        }
      } else {
        transaction.reason =
          `The ${ this.name } bakery is too low on bread stock in order to fulfill ${ customer.name }'s order.`;
      }
    } else {
      transaction.reason =
        `Customer ${ customer.name } did not provide a valid quantity for purchasing bread at ${ this.name }.`;
    }
    return transaction;
  }

  valueOf() {
    const { name, breadPrice, breadCount, moneyTotal, customers } = this;
    return {
      name, breadPrice, breadCount, moneyTotal,
      customers: customers.map(customer => customer.valueOf()),
    };
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be the maximum, which can be achieved.

```js
class ObscureEvent {
  #name;
  #event;
  constructor (options) {
    this.#name = crypto.randomUUID();
    this.#event = new CustomEvent(this.#name, options); }
  listen(target, handler) {
    target.addEventListener(this.#name, handler); }
  dispatch(target) {
    target.dispatchEvent(this.#event); } }
      
const validate = new ObscureEvent({ bubbles: true });
```

Comment: Of cause one could build a system which encloses/encapsulates everything except for e.g. an instance's _**de/register**_ / _**un/subscribe**_ methods where one could add/remove objects which each feature an own (event/topic/subject/channel specific) handler function. The dispatching instance does not have a public `dispatchEvent` method but would invoke each registered/subscribed object's specific handler function. [Something similar to this ...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77747421/2627243)

Comment: @PeterSeliger The problem with the event-strings is: they share one global name-space. Nothing prevents collisions.

Comment: Nope ... if one ties an own `EventTarget` instance to every instance of a type which is capable of dispatching events to selected (validated and registered) objects, no one except the secretly/privately dispatching instance itself is capable of accessing such dispatched events and its related data. This is due to just the dispatching instance itself can access the dispatching object. The instance itself controls the de/registering of objects which each have to be capable of handling such controlled dispatched (and otherwise not accessible) event-types.

Comment: 1/2 ... Regarding ... _"The problem with the event-strings is: they share one global name-space. Nothing prevents collisions."_ ... the event-dispatching of `EventTarget` implements a type-safe _**Signals and Slot**_ approach. Nobody can fake/intercept/spoof the event which gets created at the `addEventListeners`  invocation time. In addition, at an event-target's `dispatchEvent` time only the event-type specific handler functions (each assigned as an created listeners `handleEvent` method) which have been registered at this very event-target are going to be invoked.

Comment: 2/2 ... Combining, like suggested (and meanwhile demonstrated), a pub-sub implementation via `addSubscriber/s` / `removeSubscriber/s` with the enclosed (privately held)  functionality of an event-target enables both, the privacy and the type-safety of event-dispatching.